# Bootstrap 3: Push/pull columns over rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have the layout on mobiles like that:

```
 --------- 
|    1    |  
 --------- 
|    2    |  
 --------- 
|    3    |  
 ---------
```

for larger screens, i want to have it like that:

```
 -----------------------------------
|        1               |     3    |
 -----------------------------------
|                 2                 |
 -----------------------------------
```

Code, which does not work, because pull/push over one row :-(

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-9 alert alert-info">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3  col-sm-push-3 alert alert-warning">
         2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-3 alert alert-debug">
         3
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QtPd2/27/

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 5):

As pushing and pulling works by setting a `left` or `right` property it will never wrap to another row as you noted.

A solution is to duplicate the contents of either column 2 or 3 (take the one with the least amount of content or interactivity). Hide one one `xs` and the other on `sm`, `md` and `lg`.

In the example below I've duplicated column 2.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 alert alert-info">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-warning hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 alert alert-danger">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 alert alert-warning hidden-xs">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** There is no need to add a `.clearfix` on a `.row` as it already contains that. Even if you want a column to be 12 wide on the smallest layout, always add a `.col-xs-12` class as it adds `padding` used to negate the negative `margin` on the `.row`.

Comment: No clever way to keep this [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)? (That said, thanks for the help. At least it's a solution!)

Comment: Not really, one solution that I've used for this is to have a piece of JavaScript listen to breakpoint changes and move the content around. Another one might be to look into flexbox and the order property and implement your own grid structure

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 alert alert-info">
      1
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3 col-md-push-3 alert alert-warning">
       2
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3 col-md-pull-3 alert alert-debug">
       3
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This example only works because all three md widths do not total more than 12. Pushing and pulling columns that are *wrapped* is the issue that the OP is seeking a solution to.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2017

This may be another option for some. This layout is now natively possible in Bootstrap 4 using flexbox ordering. **No duplicate code** is required. 1-3-2 on large, 1-2-3 on mobile.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 flex-md-last flex-unordered">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/Tg7XcOOz6N