# Bootstrap column pushing/pulling issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I thought that I understand how `pushing` and `pulling` columns work...but I guess I was wrong.  I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McHolty/ujrwyrbr/65/) where I created a very simple grid.  It looks like this while in `xs`:

> Insured Name
>
> Face AMount
>
> Gender
>
> Product

and then when I am in `sm`, it looks like thus:

> Insured Name      |   Face Amount
>
> Gender    |   Product

I'm all good thus far.  However, when I get to `md` I need the Face Amount and Gender fields to switch places.  As you can see (from the fiddle) I tried to `push` the FaceAmount field 6 columns (I expected that this field would then be pushed down into the next row) and then `pull` the Gender field 6 columns (thus pulling it up a row).

However, if you pull the fiddle out to the `md` viewpoint...the FaceAmount column is pushed way off to the right (instead of wrapping down) and the Gender field is pulled way to the left to the point where you can't even see it anymore.

Is there something that I am missing?  I would have expected that since I am pushing the FaceAmount field passed the 12 column mark that it would wrap down.  Similarly, I expected the Gender field to be pulled up to the previous row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right by saying:

> I am pushing the FaceAmount field passed the 12 column mark

Also, you seem to understand to use `push` and `pull`. The problem in the jsfiddle is that you trying to rearrange between two different rows. For example, you can push `Insured Name` and pull `Face Amount` using:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  
            <div class="well"> 1 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
            <div class="well"> 3 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-0 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
            <div class="well"> 2 </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix hidden-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> 4 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> 5 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> 6 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Result:

[image]

But while doing between different rows it doesn't work that way. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123653/bootstrap-3-push-pull-columns-over-rows) article:

> As pushing and pulling works by setting a left or right property it will never wrap to another row as you noted.

[Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap) is a very good article to understand how push and pull works.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I knew about pushing and pulling on the same row...I just assumed that if you pushed an item beyond the 12 mark that it would auto wrap down to the next row.  I think that this is how it should be.

Comment: Just like if I have 2 items (and they are both col-6), when I go to add another col-6 item (thus going beyond the 12 column mark), it is put on the next row automatically.  Similar, if I did a col-push that went beyond that same 12 column mark...I expected it to be put on the next row, too.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I wish it was that way feels intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

This work! http://jsfiddle.net/ujrwyrbr/68/

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                    Insured Name:
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                    Some Name
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                Face Amount:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                Some Amount
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                Gender:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                Male
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                Product:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                Some Product
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this to work if you can use the `col-md-3` viewport on `md` and show 4 columns across.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 trRight">
                    Insured Name:
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 trLeft">
                    x
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 trRight">
                    Face Amount:
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 trLeft">
                    x
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 trRight">
                    Gender:
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 trLeft">
                    x
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 trRight">
                    Product:
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 trLeft">
                    x
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Remember too that nested `cols` should be inside another `row`.
http://www.codeply.com/go/AMAmnvznK6

Comment: I unfortunately cannot go 4 columns wide.  Out of curiosity...why should nested `cols` go inside a `row`?

Comment: To ensure [proper padding and alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting). Otherwise the spacing is off: http://www.codeply.com/go/SiZGV21hyW